# Splitting string using different scenarios using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have 2 scenarios so split a string
scenario 1:

```
"@#$hello?? getting good.<li>hii"
```

I want to be split as `'hello','getting','good.<li>hii` (Scenario 1)

```
'hello','getting','good','li,'hi' (Scenario 2)
```

Any ideas please??

Comment: What are the requirements? It is unclear what should happen to `<<<hello>>>> no.good`, or `"@#$hello?? getting good. <li>hii"`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
>>> re.split(r"[^\w<>.]+", s) # or re.split(r"[@#$? ]+", s)
['', 'hello', 'getting', 'good.<li>hii']
>>> re.split(r"[^\w]+", s)
['', 'hello', 'getting', 'good', 'li', 'hii']
```

Comment: I am sorry for not conveying the question clearly, In Scenario 2 I need only the alphanumerics (letters, numbers and underscore)

Comment: To do the same as above but including an underscore and not inducing '.' or '<>' use [^\w_]+

Answer (score 0):

This might be what your looking for \w+ it matches any digit or letter from 1 to n times as many times as possible. Here is a working Java-Script

```js
var value = "@#$hello?? getting good.<li>hii";
var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("\\w+", "gi")
);
console.log(matches)
```

It works by using \w+ which matches word characters as many times as possible. You cound also use [A-Za-b] to match only letters which not numbers. As show here.

```js
var value = "@#$hello?? getting good.<li>hii777bloop";
var matches = value.match(
     new RegExp("[A-Za-z]+", "gi")
);
console.log(matches)
```

It matches what are in the brackets 1 to n timeas as many as possible. In this case the range a-z of lower case charactors and the range of A-Z uppder case characters. Hope this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking for solution *without* `regex`. [`string.punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) will give you list of all special characters. 
Use this list with *list comprehension* for achieving your desired result as:

```
>>> import string
>>> my_string = '@#$hello?? getting good.<li>hii'
>>> ''.join([(' ' if s in string.punctuation else s) for s in my_string]).split()
['hello', 'getting', 'good', 'li', 'hii'] # desired output
```

---

***Explanation:*** Below is the step by step instruction regarding how it works:

```
import string # Importing the 'string' module
special_char_string = string.punctuation
# Value of 'special_char_string': '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'

my_string = '@#$hello?? getting good.<li>hii'

# Generating list of character in sample string with
# special character replaced with whitespace 
my_list = [(' ' if item in special_char_string else item) for item in my_string]

# Join the list to form string
my_string = ''.join(my_list)

# Split it based on space
my_desired_list = my_string.strip().split()
```

The value of `my_desired_list` will be:

```
['hello', 'getting', 'good', 'li', 'hii']
```

Answer (score 0):

For first scenario just use `regex` to find all words that are contain word characters and `<>.`:

```
In [60]: re.findall(r'[\w<>.]+', s)
Out[60]: ['hello', 'getting', 'good.<li>hii']
```

For second one you need to repleace the repeated characters only if they are not valid english words, you can do this using `nltk` corpus, and `re.sub` regex:

```
In [61]: import nltk

In [62]: english_vocab = set(w.lower() for w in nltk.corpus.words.words())

In [63]: repeat_regexp = re.compile(r'(\w*)(\w)\2(\w*)')

In [64]: [repeat_regexp.sub(r'\1\2\3', word) if word not in english_vocab else word for word in re.findall(r'[^\W]+', s)]
Out[64]: ['hello', 'getting', 'good', 'li', 'hi']
```